# Ubuntu cronjob without saving output

Tags: ubuntu, cron, wget

I want to call a php script on my VPS with cronjob, but I want it to do simple get request, without saving any logs, outputs and ect., just to make the php file to do its job, I don't want unnecessary files on my VPS. So, this is my command:

```
* * * * * wget -q -O - http://example.com/cronjob/save_currency_rates
```

Is this what I need? I'm not sure if this command saves some files, I'm not familiar with linux so far. I read the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) but it is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `wget -q -O - http://example.com/cronjob/save_currency_rates >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: What is the difference? What di the last to parameters behind the path: **>/dev/null 2>&1**

Comment: It makes sure, all output is suppressed - so no logs, not output, no mail

Comment: OK, I will accept this answer, it's correct, though it's not well explained. I did a little research and found out what exatly these strange things **>/dev/null 2>&1** mean. You can see the explanation here [link](http://goo.gl/tJqQgL).

Answer (score 0):

Run the cronjob as a standard user in privileged directory where only root should have access. So it will run the job without saving the output. But in cron logs you will get an error saying `unable to write permission denied` run it like:

```
*  *    * * *   ubuntu    wget https://google.com
```